# Powershell ssh comand in C# input arguments

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I wanted the powershell to stay open with the arguments just waiting for the password input, but every time it starts and closes automatically, could someone help me?

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe";

startInfo.Arguments = "ssh root@10.10.30.4 -p 8022"; //Here its closed

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
process.WaitForExit();
```

after `process.Start`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: And because you seem unsure about your solution...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."